# Serial NO starting from 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a query in which, I want one columns as `SR_No` which *should start from 1*

Below is my query

```
SELECT         
top 2      
 userName,   
 Party_name, 
 Ref_No,
 Ref_date,   
 doc_date,
 Last_Action_date,
 RAName,          
 COUNT(Doc_No) AS CountofDocNo,                  
 Document_Type,           
 RA1_Email                  
FROM #MainTempTable         
 GROUP BY RAName,          
 userName,           
 Document_Type,          
 RA1_Email ,Party_name,Ref_No,
 Ref_date, doc_date,Last_Action_date
 order by RAName
```

How to start it's serial no from 1.

I tried with `Row_NUM()` but it was not starting from 1.

**UPDATE**

I tried Madhivnan's solution but it didn't worked for my second query

```
SELECT         
top 2  
 row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as SR_No,      
 UserName,
 RAName,
 Party_Name,     
 Ref_No,
 Ref_date, 
 doc_date,   
 Last_Action_date,
 Document_Type,           
 Doc_No,           
 No_Of_Days_Doc_Pending,           
 UserEmail,RA1_Email                  
 FROM #MainTempTable    order by UserName
```

Comment: What is a piece of code you try with ROW_NUM()?

Comment: @Edward: I tried something like this `1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY userName) AS [SR_No]` and in `order by` as `SR_NO`

Comment: And why did you add 1 to it? Since `ROW_NUMBER()` is defined to number rows starting at 1, if you first tried it as `1+ROW_NUMBER()` and you were getting numbers starting at 2, did you not think there was an obvious fix here?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: yup, I missed that. Thanks for reminding the same

Comment: Also, `TOP 2` without a controlling `ORDER BY` clause is "please select 2 arbitrary rows" - so it's more likely that the issue you're facing is that you're not controlling the `TOP`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: actually the query's output has so many records, so for checking the sr_no i just made that as `TOP 2`

Comment: In what way is it not working? Perhaps you should have posted your 'second query' to start with so we could pose a solution once.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: The SR_No is not starting with 1 for the second query. It's starting from any point. for ex: 22,23,...

Comment: Change the `(select 0)` to match the actual order of data. i.e. change `(select 0)` to `UserName`, as per the answer by @Edward. Then read and understand how `ROW_NUMBER()` works

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: yes got that working for second one too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT         
top 2 row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as SR_No,     
 userName,   
 Party_name, 
 Ref_No,
 Ref_date,   
 doc_date,
 Last_Action_date,
 RAName,          
 COUNT(Doc_No) AS CountofDocNo,                  
 Document_Type,           
 RA1_Email                  
FROM #MainTempTable         
 GROUP BY RAName,          
 userName,           
 Document_Type,          
 RA1_Email ,Party_name,Ref_No,
 Ref_date, doc_date,Last_Action_date    
order by RAName
```

Comment: This is "please assign random numbers to my rows" - if you want some determinism here, you use expressions based on your data and your requirements rather than `(select 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be work in your case:

```
SELECT         
top 2      
 userName,   
 Party_name, 
 Ref_No,
 Ref_date,   
 doc_date,
 Last_Action_date,
 RAName,          
 COUNT(Doc_No) AS CountofDocNo,                  
 Document_Type,           
 RA1_Email,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RAName) AS SR_No                 
FROM #MainTempTable         
 GROUP BY RAName,          
 userName,           
 Document_Type,          
 RA1_Email ,Party_name,Ref_No,
 Ref_date, doc_date,Last_Action_date
```

Answer (score 0):

This one could help you

```
select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( order by field1) as rownumber,field2,field3 from dbo.yourtable
```